# how to map rails slug url to id for using in where in condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my input sample which has 3 slug url,

```
["[\"apple-iphone\"", " \"blackberry\"", " \"htc\"]"]
```

How can I convert the above slug as `id` so that I can use it as `Post.where(category_id: converted_ids)`

I used friendly_id to create slug url.

Consider I have two relations

1. categories(category name will act as slug).
2. posts(category_id is stored as reference).

And consider this as my url

```
http://localhost:3000/apple-iphone_htc_blackberry
```

Now how can I find the all the `posts with id of apple-iphone, htc, blackberry.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the algorithm you used to generate the slug.

In your case, I assume you are applying some sort of transformation to a category name or title. In this case, it can be quite hard to perform a 1 to 1 conversion from the slug to the ID.

You have several choices:

1. Change the algorithm to embed the id of the record along with the slug

   ```
   def to_param
     "#{id}-#{name.parameterize}"
   end
   ```

   This is the simplest approach because you can pass the slug as it is to the find

   ```
   Category.find("10-apple-iphone")
   ```

   that is equivalent to

   ```
   Category.find("10")
   ```
2. If you can't keep the id or you don't want (as you did), then the best way is to store the slug inside the Category record itself and perform a find by such field.

   ```
   def to_param
     slug
   end

   Category.where(slug: "apple-iphone").first
   ```

   Of course, you will need to add a migration to create the field, add a validation to make sure two records don't contain the same field, and make sure to generate the slug on creation.

Comment: I have edited my question for more detailed explanation. Can you please check

Comment: The problem is the same. Unless you save those values in the DB, you cannot easily query for them because you cannot reverse the slug into the original title or id. The `friendly_id` function you use is one-way, you cannot get the record from the slug because the function is not `surjective` (the only way to make it as such is to also store the slug inside the category model).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, then ill change It as you said